# jQuery inputmask makes CKEditor adapter to stop working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, webkit, ckeditor, jquery-inputmask

#### I have the following form:

- *Publish Start* - 2x `input`s, one for time, one for date;
- *Publish End* - 2x `input`s, one for time, one for date;
- *Post Content* - 1x `textarea`.

The inputs for date/time use [jQuery InputMask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) and textarea use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (with [jQuery Adapter](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.2/adapters/jquery.js), to expose ckeditor to `$()` and `val()`).

With the adapter, I can:

- use `$('#idOfTextarea').val()` instead of `CKEDITOR.instances['idOfTextarea'].getData();`
- use `$('#idOfTextarea').val('some value')` instead of `CKEDITOR.instances['idOfTextarea'].setData('some value');`

#### The problem:

- IE *(v9)* and Webkits *(Chrome v30 & v31, Safari v5.1)*: `val()` stops working the moment I bind the inputs with inputmask;
- Firefox *(v22)* and Opera *(v12.16)*: keep working `val()`

#### Demo:

Here is the example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/QjVf8/

1. Write something on CKEditor and test it with both ***print ckeditor .val() on console*** and ***print ckeditor .getData() on console*** links.
2. Click on ***bind inputmask on above inputs*** and then click on the print tests again. The `val()` will stop working, while the `getData` *(native ck implementation)* will keep working.

I couldn't find if the problem is with the adapter or inputmask :(

---

### Update:

I discovered that both ck adapter and inputmask makes an `$.extend` on `$.fn.val`. Seems `$.fn.val` is getting overwritten on the browsers that adapter stop working, instead of actually extended (imo, had to hold both extends, no?)

`$.fn.val` before inputmask (chrome):

```
function(d) {
    if (arguments.length) {
        var k = this,
            i = [],
            f = this.each(function() {
                var b = a(this),
                    c = b.data("ckeditorInstance");
                if (b.is("textarea") && c) {
                    var f = new a.Deferred;
                    c.setData(d, function() {
                        f.resolve()
                    });
                    i.push(f.promise());
                    return !0
                }
                return g.call(b, d)
            });
        if (i.length) {
            var b = new a.Deferred;
            a.when.apply(this, i).done(function() {
                b.resolveWith(k)
            });
            return b.promise()
        }
        return f
    }
    var f = a(this).eq(0),
        c = f.data("ckeditorInstance");
    return f.is("textarea") && c ? c.getData() : g.call(f)
}
```

`$.fn.val` after inputmask (chrome):

```
function() {
    var t, i, r;
    return arguments.length == 0 ? (t = n(this), t.data("inputmask") ? t.data("inputmask").autoUnmask ? t.inputmask("unmaskedvalue") : (i = n.inputmask.val.apply(t), i != t.data("inputmask")._buffer.join("") ? i : "") : n.inputmask.val.apply(t)) : (r = arguments, this.each(function() {
        var t = n(this),
            i = n.inputmask.val.apply(t, r);
        return t.data("inputmask") && t.triggerHandler("setvalue.inputmask"), i
    }))
}
```

While on Firefox, `$.fn.val` is always the same (does not change when I call inputmask).

Is there a way I can merge inputmask's extend with ckeditor one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that encounter this error someday, I've talked with [RobinHerbots](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/) (creator of [jquery-inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/) ) and seems that the problem is:

The `n.inputmask.val.apply(t, r);` does the call to the original `fn.val` code.
So inputmask make the ref when it was inserted onto html (instead of when it's called via `$(selector).inputmask()`). It caches the `$.fn.val` onto `$.inputmask.val` but just actually extend it it when called using `.inputmask()`. Then ckeditor modifies later the val (was called later) but since inputmask has cached the original val from before ckeditor extend, it overwrites the ckeditor one.

---

Using this idea as base, I tested moving the ckeditor scripts to before the inputmask script. I made a rev on the fiddle changing the script for last http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/QjVf8/8/ (see external resources).

Seems it worked on the browsers who were showing an overwritten `$.fn.val` now :dancer:

For more info, check https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/issues/319